# How to resolve Kernel Panic error after upgrading F15 to F17 using Preupgrade?

Tags: linux, upgrade, fedora, kernel-panic

I tried to upgrade my Fedora 15 to Fedora 17 directly using Preupgrade. Everything went smooth and the updates were installed. Grub2 screen came up after the restart. When I chose to boot F17, I got a kernel panic error.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Need more information. Like, what is the actual error ?

Comment: The error is something like, "VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)"

Comment: try using the dvd and doing the upgrade that way. I had that issue myself on 2 systems with preupgrade.

Comment: It worked. So this means, it is better not to use preupgrade?

Comment: preupgrade is pretty new (new to F17 i think). It has a few bugs still, but i suspect in F18 it'll "just work"